# What Design process should you follow as a design lead? Are there any ways you can make it easy for your juniors?

Tags: website-design, typography, interface-design, designers, design-process

Say, I want to make it easy for my juniors to follow a design process so that it help them from missing the deadlines and work in an organised manner, so that they enjoy while working.

Comment: Hi Sakshi Bhardwaj, welcome to GD.SE. I think your question is a bit broad, you should focus on the objective of what do you specifically want to know. The graphic design profession is very extensive and covers several specializations. Although the design process can be similar in many cases, it's different for each design action and project type. Motivating a creative designer could be different than a layout person. A design process to create a flyer could be not the same as for the design of a city signage. Products, times, things to do, personal involved, etc. everything is different.